# How to render a rainbow spectrum?

Tags: c++, qt

I have the need to programmatically generate the approximation of a rainbow spectrum, in a rectangular image, as shown below:

[image: rainbow spectrum]

I know how to draw the pixmap, what I'm looking for is how to generate the values of the colors.

Comment: QT has the QColor class where you can set the hue and you can get the RGB from it

Comment: Have a look at this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/paintsystem.html, it has everything you need to know. Once you've done some reading / learning, come back and post a specific programming problem if you get stuck.

Comment: Are you really asking 1) how to compute the RGB (or HSL, HSV, etc.) value for each location on the bar, or 2) how to create the bar given the correct colors, or 3) both?

Comment: Question has been edited into something interesting. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, how to create the bar given the correct colors that I have displayed.

Comment: Should not have been closed.  The original poster demonstrated a partial understanding of the problem by pointing out that he/she knows how to draw the bitmap, but not how to compute it.  Besides, this has value to future answer-seekers who already have a deeper knowledge than the original poster.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to [read this paper](http://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/specrend/). Seriously.

Other than that, all it could take is to iterate through hues in the HSL color representation, using `QColor::fromHslF(x/*0.8, 0.95, 0.5)` where `x` varies from 0.0 to 1.0 over the rainbow. It's not physically accurate at all, but maybe it would do.

Otherwise, you need a slightly more complex code that very simplistically approximates the paper cited above.

[image: screenshot]

```cpp
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/rainbow-19452530
#include <QtGui>
#if QT_VERSION_MAJOR > 4
#include <QtWidgets>
#endif
#include <array>
#include <cmath>

constexpr qreal linMap(qreal x1, qreal x, qreal x2, qreal y1 = 0., qreal y2 = 1.) {
   return y1 + (y1 - y2) * (x - x1) / (x1 - x2);
}

QColor wavelengthToColor(qreal lambda) {
   // Based on: http://www.efg2.com/Lab/ScienceAndEngineering/Spectra.htm
   // The foregoing is based on: http://www.midnightkite.com/color.html
   struct Color {
      qreal red = 0., green = 0., blue = 0.;
      QColor toColor(qreal factor) const {
         auto const map = [factor](qreal c) -> qreal {
            constexpr qreal gamma = 0.8;
            return pow(c * factor, gamma);
         };
         return QColor::fromRgbF(map(red), map(green), map(blue));
      }
   };
   struct Threshold {
      qreal begin, end;
      Color (*color)(qreal);
      qreal (*factor)(qreal) = nullptr;
   };
   static const std::array<Threshold, 8> thresholds{
      // Let the intensity fall off near the vision limits
      Threshold{380, 420, nullptr, [](qreal x){ return 0.3 + 0.7*x; }},
      Threshold{380, 440, [](qreal x){ return Color{1-x, 0, 1}; }},
      Threshold{440, 490, [](qreal x){ return Color{0, x, 1}; }},
      Threshold{490, 510, [](qreal x){ return Color{0, 1, 1-x}; }},
      Threshold{510, 580, [](qreal x){ return Color{x, 1, 0}; }},
      Threshold{580, 645, [](qreal x){ return Color{1, 1-x, 0}; }},
      Threshold{645, 780, [](qreal  ){ return Color{1, 0, 0}; }},
      Threshold{700, 780, nullptr, [](qreal x){ return 1 - 0.7*x; }}
   };

   Color color;
   qreal factor = 1.0;
   for (auto &thr : thresholds) {
      if (lambda < thr.begin || lambda >= thr.end) continue;
      auto x = linMap(thr.begin, lambda, thr.end);
      if (thr.factor) factor = thr.factor(x);
      if (thr.color) color = thr.color(x);
   }
   return color.toColor(factor);
}

QPixmap rainbow(int w, int h) {
   QPixmap pixmap(w, h);
   QPainter p(&pixmap);
   constexpr qreal f1 = 1.0 / 400, f2 = 1.0 / 780;
   for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
      // Iterate across frequencies, not wavelengths
      auto freq = linMap(0, x, w, f1, f2);
      p.setPen(wavelengthToColor(1.0 / freq));
      p.drawLine(x, 0, x, h);
   }
   return pixmap;
}

class RainbowLabel : public QLabel {
  protected:
   void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *) override { setPixmap(rainbow(width(), height())); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   RainbowLabel l;
   l.resize(600, 100);
   l.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: +1.  Thanks for the reference to that paper.  It's one of the clearest and most useful explanations I've read of rendering color properly.